# Why is IIS missing (deactivated) after Windows Update..?

Tags: windows-10, updates, iis

Seems to be related to KB3176936. Several installations are affected by this same update. All instances are missing the IIS features immediately after the update. Going to Programs and Features the option is there, but it has been unchecked during the update. I checked it again, but then I had to recreate everything just like a new install.

(Windows 10 on all instances)

Comment: which version of windows are you talking about?  7? 8? 10? Server?  we need a bit more detail..

Comment: This is Windows10 in the three cases with which I'm dealing.

Comment: please edit the tags and the question to reflect that.   Are you saying that when you go to Programs and Features > Windows Features > the option to install IIS is no longer present?   Or are you saying that your existing IIS install is not working?

Comment: screenshots would be handy

Comment: IIS is missing. Going to Programs and Features the option is there, but it has been unchecked during the update. I checked it again, but then I had to recreate everything just like a new install.

Comment: Ouch.   Have you checked to see if it created a restore point before it installed the update?

Comment: I didn't bother with chasing restore points. The need to function was more urgent. I just recreated the virtual directories and applications.

Comment: Confirm that I have the same on Windows 10 Pro after latest update. IIS has been removed and I have had to re-configure from scratch. Totally not cool.

Comment: It happened to me also. This is just great, settings, websites, dev certs, custom app pools.

Answer (score 3):

The "good" news is that there seems to be a way to restore the IIS app pools and sites (after re-enabling IIS from "Turn Windows features on or off")

It’s a little tricky and error prone, but it’s better than nothing.

Here is the procedure that worked for me:

1. In a text editor, open `C:\Windows.old\WINDOWS\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`. This is the original IIS data from before the update.
2. In another text editor open `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`. This is the active IIS data.
3. Replace the `<applicationPools>` and `<sites>` elements in the active file with those from the original
4. Run `iisreset` from an elevated command prompt

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184735/270348